# How to automatically change input.timeframe('D') to a period greater than the user's chart. PineScript V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm newbie. I have a Pine script code.

Problem with function:

```
input.timeframe('D')
```

I need the script to call an asset formula time higher than the one used in real time.

I use a function:

```
request.security()
```

Error calling string with mutable variable:

```
input.timeframe(VAR)
```

Return error:

```
An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.
```

To call up an asset with timeframe different from the real user timeframe.

When I use the HOURS time chart.
The indicator function should call the upper time ie days = 'D' .

Or

When real time is 'D'. The indicator function should call the upper time ie week = 'W' .

I want Automatic Time Search function.

And also that the user chooses timeframe manually in an Optional way.

The code EXAMPLE is as follows:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="My Indicator", shorttitle="My Indicator", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

timeframe_automatic = (timeframe.isintraday ? 'D' : timeframe.isdaily ? 'W' : timeframe.isweekly ? 'M' : na)

timeframe_options = input.timeframe((timeframe_automatic), "Resolution Big", options=['D', 'W', 'M'])

timeframe_called = (request.security(syminfo.tickerid, (timeframe_options), close, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off))
```

The Pine Script compiler requires a 'String Const' for input.timeframe('D') as well as 'D'.

And refuses when using a mutable 'Simple String' for automatic search.:

```
line xxx: Cannot call 'input.timeframe' with argument 'defval'='timeframe_options'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected.
```

I can't find proper functions in the documentation to work around this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it. Use `timeframe_automatic` in your security call.

```
timeframe_called = (request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe_automatic, close, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off))
```

Comment: My problem was to make the user decide between leaving it in automatic mode or putting it in manual mode.

As I said: timeframe_automatic = is a mutable variable.

And input.timeframe(timeframe_automatic) cannot be a mutable variable but just a const string.

But, request.security() accepts period mutable variable with the requirement that it be const string.

The solution I found was to create a manual selector for the user to select between automatic version and manual version.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to make the user decide between leaving it in automatic mode or putting it in manual mode.

```
timeframe_automatic = is a mutable variable.
```

And `input.timeframe(timeframe_automatic)` does not accept a mutable variable but just a const string.

But, `request.security()` accepts period mutable variable with the requirement that it be const string.

The solution I found was to separate the decisions into 3 different codes.

The 1st code I had to add a manual selector to select between Automatic or Manual code.

And a 2nd code for making decisions.

And finally, the 3rd code makes the function call.

The code looks like this, Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="My Indicator", shorttitle="My Indicator", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

timeframe_selector = input.string(title = "Timeframe Big", defval = "Automatic", options=["Automatic", "Manual"])

timeframe_automatic = (timeframe.isintraday ? 'D' : timeframe.isdaily ? 'W' : timeframe.isweekly ? 'M' : timeframe.ismonthly ? '12M': na)

timeframe_manual = input.timeframe('D', "Resolution Big", options=['D', 'W', 'M', '12M'])

timeframe_decision = (timeframe_selector == "Automatic") ? timeframe_automatic : (timeframe_selector == "Manual") ? timeframe_manual : na

timeframe_called = (request.security(syminfo.tickerid, (timeframe_decision), close, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off))
```

Ok now!